# import/export csv that contains [ ]

Tags: powershell, csv, import, export

I am creating a script for VMware DR within a vCloud Director environment. I have a couple scripts that generate different csv files, which contain my entire environment.  I am trying to import one of the larger all encompassing CSV files to create a csv export file that contains only lines that match the three letter code in the Name column for a specific client's VMs and the three letter code on each datastore listed in the VMXPath column that identifies if the storage is replicated.

**Script Export Goal:**
Matches ABC in the Name Column and matches either NLR or S4R in the VMXPath column.

**Example:**
For the sample below, I removed all of the other columns in the CSV file, as there are a lot of them, leaving the two columns I am trying to sort/export based on my script criteria. Here is an example of the column header and sample data contained in the csv.

```
"Name","VMXPath"
"ABC04W09A001 (74342f44-cd05-490e-87bc-3803e8656b33)","[NLR_ABC_DST_505] ABC04W09A001 (74342f44-cd05-490e-87bc-3803e8656b33)/ABC04W09A001 (74342f44-cd05-490e-87bc-3803e8656b33).vmx"
```

Here is the script code that i am using which is failing to generate the proper export file. I can get it to match Client ABC but even when i strip the command down to just trying to export only based on the VMXPath criteria it still fails.

```
    $drinventory = Import-Csv C:\reports\dr\co_prod_all_inventory.csv

    $abcinventory | where {($_.Name -match “abc”) -and ($_.VMXPath -match "NLR" -or "S4R")} | Export-Csv C:\reports\dr\abc_dr.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I am not sure what the root cause might be.  I feel like it might have something to do with the [ ] as i think that is what an array would be contained in? I am somewhat new to powershell, and basically can piece things together from this site/google.

Any help that you can provide is greatly appreciated and thank you very much ahead of time.

ps. i apologize if this isn't properly formatted to conform to the standards of this site. I am new to posting things here and I know that VM Name/ VMXPath information is kind of long...

Comment: `“abc”` - these aren't the standard ASCII doublequotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a regex

- the `[` denotes the begin of a character class, so it has to be
  escaped with a backslash when matching it literal.
- to anchor a pattern at the begin you use the `^` (for the end a `$`)
- to negate/inverse a character class the same caret `[^ ]` is used (here it means everything but a space)
- the `|` marks an or condition in a pattern, it matches one or the other.

So this script works properly even with some more generated test data:

```
$drinventory = Import-Csv ".\co_prod_all_inventory.csv"
$drinventory | 
  where {($_.Name -match "^abc") -and ($_.VMXPath -match "^\[NLR|^\[S4R")} | 
    Export-Csv ".\abc_dr.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thank you very much for answering this for me. This is exactly what i was looking for and my script works flawlessly now. I appreciate you explaining how your changes work as well, as now I am educated for the future as well.  thanks again!!